# Grid lines disappear when using ggarrange with common.legend = TRUE

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two plots I'm trying to present together using ggarrange, but y grid lines disappear when doing so using common.legend = TRUE.

Here's how it looks **without** common.legend = TRUE:

```
ggarrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Setting a common legend results in this:

```
ggarrange(p1,p2,common.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: Have you considered using the patchwork package for plot composition? Also, please include code and (dummy) data in your question so that we might reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - I used `theme_classic()` in both individual plots, the problem was solved when I removed it, so now the unified plot looks like this:
[image]

I still can't understand why this problem occurred, but at least I managed to find a way around it.